# SICP Exercise 1.5

Tags: scheme, sicp

> **Exercise 1.5.**  Ben Bitdiddle has invented a test to determine whether the interpreter he is faced with is using applicative-order
>   evaluation or normal-order evaluation. He defines the following two
>   procedures:
>
> (define (p) (p))
>
> (define (test x y)   (if (= x 0)
>         0
>         y))
>
> Then he evaluates the expression
>
> (test 0 (p))
>
> What behavior will Ben observe with an interpreter that uses
>   applicative-order evaluation? What behavior will he observe with an
>   interpreter that uses normal-order evaluation?

I understand the answer to the exercise; my question lies in how (p) is interpreted versus p. For example, (test 0 (p)) causes the interpreter to hang (which is expected), but (test 0 p) with the above definition immediately evaluates to 0. Why?

Moreover, suppose we changed the definition to (define (p) p). With the given definition, (test 0 (p)) and (test 0 p) both evaluate to 0. Why does this occur? Why doesn't the interpreter hang? I am using Dr. Racket with the SICP package.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`p` is a function.  `(p)` is a call to a function.

In your interpreter evaluate `p`.

```
p <Return>
==>  P : #function
```

Now evaluate `(p)`.  Make sure you know how to kill your interpreter!  (Probably there is a “Stop” button in Dr. Racket.)

```
(p)
```

Note that nothing happens.  Or, at least, nothing visible.  The interpreter is spinning away, eliminating tail calls (so, using near 0 memory), calling `p`.

As `p` and `(p)` evaluate to different things, you should expect different behaviour.

As to your second question : You are defining `p` to be a function that returns itself.  Again, try evaluating `p` and `(p)` with your `(define (p) p)` and see what you get.  My guess (I am using a computer on which I cannot install anything and which has no scheme) is that they will evaluate to the same thing.  (I might even bet that `(eq? p (p))` will evaluate to `#t`.)

Comment: Thanks. I also looking for the answer.